# How can I read all documents in Cloudant and proess individual msg objects on NodeRED?

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb, cloudant, node-red

I'm reading a complete cloudant/apache couchdb database using the node-red cloudant connector and basically getting back a single big array of JSON objects (which I already don't like :) but anyway, what is the way (e.g. using a node-red javascript function) to transform this array into individual node-red messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split` node for just this purpose.

If the `msg.payload` it is passed contains an array, it emits a message for each element of that array.